# Intelligencia.UrlRewriter check domain to redirect to https

Tags: asp.net, regex, url, urlrewriter.net

I'm having a problem trying to force https on my website while **excluding locahost**
I'm currently using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter to rewrite any urls and I have the following rule set up:

```
<if header="HTTPS" match="^OFF$">
<redirect url="(.*)" to="https://sub.mydomain.com$1" />
</if>
```

This redirects fine, but I would like to make sure that my localhost debugging is not affected. This obviously runs under a different URL.  So I tried:

```
<if header="HTTPS" match="^OFF$">
<redirect url="(.*)mydomain" to="https://sub.mydomain.com$1" />
</if>
```

This however does not work. I believe the reason for that might be that it **only evaluates anything after the .com.** 
I have tried searching for documentation with no luck.

How can I always force https connection except on my localhost?

Comment: Do you want to match anything but a URL with `mydomain`? Try `url="^(?!.*mydomain)(.*)"`

Comment: I'm trying to exclude localhost. I've edited the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem:

```
<unless header="HTTP_HOST" match="localhost">
  <if header="HTTPS" match="^OFF$">
    <redirect url="(.*)" to="https://sub.mydomain.com$1" />
  </if>
</unless>
```

With the addition of the `<unless header="HTTP_HOST" match="localhost">` tag I can exclude certain hosts and still allow other hosts to be redirected to **https**. In other words:

This will be forced:

---

> ```
> http://sub.mydomain.com/default.html
> ```

To (note the s in https):

> https://sub.mydomain.com/defualt.html

---

But this will **not be changed**:

> http://localhost/default.html

---